# Box around text, image in corner of said box. How do I do it?

Tags: graphics, minipage

Trying to create something like this, with the red blob being the illustration:

[image]

I tried messing around with `minipage` and `hrule`/`vrule` but so far no luck. You'll need an image file named `ill.<suffix>` to compile this not-really-working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\hrule width10cm
Sample text here.
\hrule width9cm \includegraphics[width=8mm,height=8mm]{ill}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is quite easy with `tcolorbox` and its `overlay` feature, placing a node at `frame.south east`, the node content is an `\includegraphics` command here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,sharp corners,
  width={10cm},
  colback=white,
  overlay={\node at (frame.south east) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{ente}};} ]
Sample text here.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**With a 'blob'**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,sharp corners,
  width={10cm},
  colback=white,
  overlay={\node[circle,fill,red] at (frame.south east) { A };} ]
Sample text here.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

**With blue frame**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,sharp corners,
  width={10cm},
  colback=white,
  overlay={\node[rectangle,draw,blue,line width=10pt] at (frame.south east) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{ente}};} ]
Sample text here.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @egreg: blob = duck ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Bonus question: How do I get a white frame of a certain thickness around the duck?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard:   `overlay={\node[rectangle,draw,white,line width=20pt] at (frame.south east) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{ente}};}`, for example

Comment: Hurm, that gives me `Runaway argument?`. Current code: 

`\newcommand{\intro}[1]{%  
\begin{centering}  
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,sharp corners,%  
  width={8cm},%  
  colback=white,%  
  overlay={\node[rectangle,draw,white,line width=20pt] at (frame.south east)   
  {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{ente}};}%  
#1%  
\end{tcolorbox}%  
\end{centering}  
\vspace{2em}  
}`

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard: See the update please, (with blue frame, to make it more outstanding just for demonstration). The `\begin{centering}...\end{centering}` does not look really healthy

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thank you, now it works. Is there a way to protect the frame and image so it won't get overlapped by text? And also, why do ou consider `centering` a bad choice, if I may ask?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard: `centering` is no environment ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In ConTeXt, it is possible to achieve this effect by using [Layers](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers) and [Overlays](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Overlays). In the example below, I define a new frame called `cowframe` which places a cow at the bottom right corner of the frame.

```
\setupexternalfigures[location={local,default}]

\definelayer[cowframe][width=\overlaywidth, height=\overlayheight]

\startsetups cowframe
  \setlayer[cowframe]
           [corner={right,bottom}, location={middle,middle}]
           {\externalfigure[cow][height=3\lineheight]}
\stopsetups

\defineoverlay[cowframe][{\directsetup{cowframe}\tightlayer[cowframe]}]

\defineframed
  [cowframe]
  [
    frame=on,
    background=cowframe,
    align={normal,hyphenated},
    width=8cm,
    offset=0.5em,
  ]

\starttext
\cowframe{\input ward\endgraf}
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]